# How can I remove the Main Tab in Crystal Report Viewer?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

How to remove or hide the main tab section in Crystal Report Viewer (C#).

Comment: Why removing Hi and Thanks??? :-)

Comment: is this Windows Forms Report Viewer or ASPNET Report Viewer?

Answer (score 8):

Omid's answer is correct, but you have to make sure to do that stuff **after you have set the viewer's ReportSource**.  The version in my function below is a little more robust, and makes what's going on a little clearer, though I'm still not sure why doing that bit of magic to the TabControl's ItemSize and SizeMode make the tab bar go away.

```
// This is a method of a Form with one of these:
//     CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer
// This hides the tab control with the "Main Report" button.
public void hideTheTabControl()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource != null, 
        "you have to set the ReportSource first");

    foreach (Control c1 in crystalReportViewer1.Controls)
    {
        if (c1 is CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.PageView)
        {
            PageView pv = (PageView)c1;
            foreach (Control c2 in pv.Controls)
            {
                if (c2 is TabControl)
                {
                    TabControl tc = (TabControl)c2;
                    tc.ItemSize = new Size(0, 1);
                    tc.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks.

In VB it should seem like this:

```
    For Each c1 As Control In CrystalReportViewer1.Controls
        If c1.GetType Is GetType(CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.PageView) Then
            Dim pv As CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.PageView = c1
            For Each c2 As Control In pv.Controls
                If c2.GetType Is GetType(TabControl) Then
                    Dim tc As TabControl = c2
                    tc.ItemSize = New Size(0, 1)
                    tc.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution for CrystalDecisions.Web ReportViewer

Put a reference to `jquery.js` in the page and paste this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".hideableFrame").hide();
});
```

### Explanation

I found that *"Main Tab"* is placed inside a `<tr>` with `class="hideableFrame"`

```
<tr class="hideableFrame" valign="bottom" height="28" style="display: table-row;">
 <td>
   <img width="5" height="5" 
    ...
```

I could not work in a `css` file, since `style:display` is written on the element, so I wrote a script that changes the visibility to items marked as `hideableFrame`.

Note: there are 4 -USELESS- elements with `class="hideableFrame"`;  this script will hide all of them.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution of Emanuele Greco and it works but sometimes it isn't possible to add a reference in your code to jquery.
Try this in your web page

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" 
                runat="server"
                CssClass="Report"
                 HasCrystalLogo="False" 
                 HasSearchButton="False"
                  HasToggleGroupTreeButton="False" 
                   HasZoomFactorList="False" 
                  Height="100%" Width="100%" 
                  meta:resourcekey="CrystalReportViewer1Resource1"
                  EnableDrillDown="False" 
                  ReuseParameterValuesOnRefresh="True" 
                  EnableToolTips="False" ToolPanelView="None" HasDrilldownTabs="False" 
                    HasDrillUpButton="False" />
```

Comment: It's quite hard to develop a web application without JQuery for many reasons, not just for hiding Main Tab. Anyway, in this case I use Jeff Roe Solution

Answer (score 0):

```
            foreach (Control control in crystalReportViewer1.Controls)
            {

                if (control is CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.PageView)
                {

                    TabControl tab = (TabControl)(CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.PageView)control).Controls[0];

                    tab.ItemSize = new Size(0, 1);

                    tab.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;

                    tab.Appearance = TabAppearance.Buttons;

                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

set HasDrilldownTabs="false" in CrystalReportViewer control

Answer (score -1):

crystalReportViewer1.DisplayStatusBar = false;